# Can I decorate a method in C# such that it is compiled only in debug versions?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, debug-build

I'm aware that you can use `#if DEBUG` and the likes in C#, but is it possible to create a method, or class, that is ignored completely, including all usages that are **not** wrapped inside an `#if DEBUG` block?

Something like:

```
[DebugOnlyAttribute]
public void PushDebugInfo()
{
    // do something
    Console.WriteLine("world");
}
```

and then:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("hello ");
    Xxx.PushDebugInfo();
}
```

which, if `DEBUG` is defined will print "hello world", otherwise just "hello ". But more importantly, the MSIL should not contain the method-call at all in release builds.

I believe the behavior I'm after is something similar to Debug.WriteLine, whose call is completely removed and has no impact on performance or stack depth in release builds.

And, if possible in C#, would any .NET language using this method behave the same (i.e., compile-time vs run-time optimization).

*Also tagged [f#](/questions/tagged/f%23), because essentially I will need this method there.*

Comment: ConditionalDebug attribute: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for [`ConditionalAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.90).aspx).

For example, this is a portion of [`Debug` class source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/41e203011152581a6c65bb81ac44ec037140c1bb/src/Common/src/System/Diagnostics/Debug.cs):

```
static partial class Debug
{
    private static readonly object s_ForLock = new Object();

    [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void Assert(bool condition)
    {
        Assert(condition, string.Empty, string.Empty);
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void Assert(bool condition, string message)
    {
        Assert(condition, message, string.Empty);
    }
 ................................
```

Comment: Are these methods compiled in any release and removed by the JIT or are they, as MSDN says, removed by the compiler (which requires two builds for others to use, dependent on their debug settings)?

Comment: @Abel It's a compilation detail. JIT has nothing to do with this. BTW, build configurations are very easy to configure, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, they are. Anyway, it gives me enough ammo to go on. It has this "aha-erlebnis" feeling, I think I have used or seen this years ago, but forgot about it ;).

Comment: @Abel .NET ecosystem is big enough to forgot details in the long run :D

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate your method with `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` so that it is only executed in debug mode and will not be executed in Release mode.

You can read more about the Conditional attribute on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xssyw96%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which says:

> > **The Conditional attribute is often used with the `DEBUG` identifier to enable trace and logging features for debug builds but not in release builds**

Comment: Seems like the thing I was looking for. What happens then if I have `var x = Xxx.SomeDebugOnlyMethod()`? A compile time error? Do you know if something similar exists that does not require two builds, but can be optimized away by the JIT?

Comment: @Abel what you mean by ``SomeDebugOnlyMethod()`` , did'nt got your point

Comment: it will not execute the code where `x` is referenced next in release mode

Comment: Yes. No, sorry. I meant: I assign the value to a variable. If the rh-side is not compiled, it should become a compile error, right?

Comment: Just found it: _"A conditional method must be a method in a class or struct declaration and must have a return type of void."_, from MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the following method used in some places, although it might not be the best way.

```
public static class Debug
{
    public static bool IsInDebugMode { get; set; }

    public static void Print(string message)
    {
        if (IsInDebugMode) Console.Write(message);
    }
}
```

You can then set the `IsInDebugMode` boolean somewhere in your main method and do `Debug.Print("yolo")` calls all over.

EDIT: This can of course be expanded on with additional wrappers for formatted output, with automatic newline and so on.

Comment: No, this is indeed not what I was looking for, as it will still execute the method. I am trying to prevent this. In tight loops, this would have a detrimental effect on performance.

Comment: I've only used this in Java for small home projects where it's been a quick way to get debug printing up and running but yeah, if performance is critical (meaning that it's proven/demonstrably necessary to optimize) this might not be optimal (although a bool check is really cheap so you might get away with it anyway). I've never used the `ConditionalAttribute` but that looks promising so it might suit you better though.

Comment: @freedomn-m, in most cases it would suffice, it is how we use logging and log settings. But in some scenarios, I need to gather information in tight loops, in which case it would be better not to have the method-call at all. And there's the scenario, of course, with security-sensitive information that you only want to have present in debug builds.

Comment: Personally, I prefer this method as it means you can turn on debug in a production environment without needing to recompile.  However, in some cases (such as this question) the overhead it too high.